# Mysql primary key association does not use index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I have a SQL problem.

When the user, organization, and organization are associated with the table, if the user status is used to filter the table, the index user_id cannot be used. If the condition is removed, the index user_id will be used.

Why is that?

MSYQL VERSION:5.7.32-log

Below is the specific SQL and table structure.

sql 1 :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT USER
    .user_id,
    USER.NAME,
    USER.nickname,
    USER.position,
    USER.first_line_id,
    USER.second_line_id,
    USER.org_id,
    user.state
    
FROM
    USER INNER JOIN user_org  ON USER.user_id = user_org.user_id
    INNER JOIN org ON user_org.org_id = org.id 
WHERE
  ( org.end_time IS NULL OR org.end_time > NOW( ) ) 
  AND USER.state = 1 
    AND ( full_id LIKE 'H_ROOT.00000001.00000002.50060182.50091585.50095679.50092012.10148706.50092333.10161139%' )
```

[explain:user_id index not sufficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz0Bg.png)

sql2 :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT USER
    .user_id,
    USER.NAME,
    USER.nickname,
    USER.position,
    USER.first_line_id,
    USER.second_line_id,
    USER.org_id,
    user.state
FROM
    USER INNER JOIN user_org  ON USER.user_id = user_org.user_id
    INNER JOIN org ON user_org.org_id = org.id 
WHERE
  ( org.end_time IS NULL OR org.end_time > NOW( ) ) 
  -- AND USER.state = 1 
    AND ( full_id LIKE 'H_ROOT.00000001.00000002.50060182.50091585.50095679.50092012.10148706.50092333.10161139%' )
```

[explain:user_id index sufficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEoTZ.png)

table count

USER:356007

ORG:142713

USER_ORG:353088

table schema

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_org`;
CREATE TABLE `user_org`  (
  `user_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `org_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `org_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `org_id`(`org_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user`;
CREATE TABLE `user`  (
  `user_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '工号',
  `name` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '姓名',
  `email` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '邮箱',
  `email_private` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '个人邮箱',
  `mobile` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '手机号',
  `position` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT '岗位',
  `state` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '状态(1:启用；0:禁用)',
  `org_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '部门编码',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_email_index`(`email`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_mobile_index`(`mobile`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_name_index`(`name`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_org_id_index`(`org_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci COMMENT = '用户表' ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `org`;
CREATE TABLE `org`  (
  `id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `full_id` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '部门过期时间',
  `created_at` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) COMMENT '创建时间',
  `updated_at` datetime(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) COMMENT '更新时间',
  `customer_code` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT '',
  `org_type` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '组织类别',
  `state` tinyint(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ' 1  正常 2 停用\r\n冗余目前还是用endtime来识别有效性',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `org_full_id_index`(`full_id`(255)) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `org_name_index`(`name`(255)) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `org_parent_id_index`(`parent_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `end_time`(`end_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci COMMENT = '组织表' ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

[STRAIGHT_JOIN not sufficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW4gp.png)

[STRAIGHT_JOIN not sufficien v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qybuo.png)

[FORCE INDEX not sufficient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNGXF.png)

[FORCE INDEX not sufficient v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/365jg.png)

Comment: The query #1 needs in `user(state, user_id)` or, maybe, `user(user_id, state)`. PS. Pay attention - the tables scanning order differs, so the question does the index is used or not is secondary one.

Comment: @Akina I've already tried that,user(state, user_id) or user(user_id, state) index not  sufficient

Comment: Test this index forcing. Test STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: @Akina I also tried these two, nothing worked, I added the screenshot to the problem

Comment: You must test STRAIGHT_JOIN with all 8 possible JOIN expressions. You must test forcing the indices which I have recommended, not PRIMARY. And look at the execution time, not the plan only.

Comment: @Akina I tested it. You can take a look at the picture of v2

Answer (score 1):

What version of MySQL are you using?  There have been Optimization and Index-limit changes that are relevant to your query and schema.

If you set `end_time` to some date in the distant future, you could avoid the `OR` by changing to simply `end_time > NOW()`.  (`OR` used to be bad for performance.)

The indexes you have for the many-to-many table (`user_org`) are optimal.

Index "prefixing" (`full_id(255)`) is problematic.  It can be eliminated in newer versions.  `INDEX(full_id)` would let the query start with `full_id LIKE '...%' be much more usable.

Perhaps you should change to utf8mb4?  It is needed for the more obscure Chinese characters, plus some Emoji.

This index *may* be picked by the Optimizer; suggest you add it:

```
USER:  INDEX(state, user_id)
```

If you don't actually need `user.name` to be a full 256 characters, lower it to 255.  That way you can eliminate the prefixing:

```
USER:  INDEX(name)
```

See other options here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: MSYQL VERSION:5.7.32-log

Comment: Explain SQL use this index after adding user-state index
But let's get rid of state=1

Comment: full_id(255) limit has remove